# Алгоритм замены символов

Tags: алгоритм, поиск

Есть входящая строка из нескольких символов. заранее неизвестно как введены символы - на кириллице или латинице.

Нужен алгоритм который переберет все возможные варианты. Символы из заранее определенного словаря. Могут располагаться не подряд.

Например входящая строка АААА. И на выходе мы должны получить список из 16 вариантов написания.

Подскажите хотя-бы примерный алгоритм...

Comment: Если символов N — просто генерируйте все числа в системе счисления по основанию N, с подстановкой соответствующих символов...

Comment: Уточни вопрос, не совсем понятен смысл. Я не могу понять чем АА отличается от АА, почему он должен быть два раза в ответе. Или добавь чуть больше примеров (только не с 16 вариантами ответов, ограничься 8 или 4!).